# Bootstrap procedure

Tags: vba, random

I wrote this VBA code as a bootstrap procedure (unfortunately, R functions don't allow to extract every resampled series, so I had to do it with Excel and rnd):

```
Sub bootstrap()

    Dim i, j, k, l, m, n As Integer
    l = 9
    For l = 9 To 508

    For j = 5 To 4040
     Randomize
     k = Int((4040 - 5 + 1) * Rnd + 5)

    Cells(j, l + 1).Value = Cells(k, 9).Value
    Next
    Columns(l + 2).Insert
    Next

End Sub
```

Basically, I have an original column with 4036 data, and I want to randomly resample this series 500 times (hence the `For l = 9 To 508` and `For j = 5 To 4040`). So, my macro will compute 500 new columns with randomly reallocated data from the original column.

Unfortunately, the macro takes forever to run (around 45mn). How can I improve it?

Comment: I'd start with [indentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation), then [common issues](http://rubberduckvba.com/inspections/list) (disclaimer: I own that website; give inspections 35-45 seconds to run) (especially implicit references to the active worksheet), then toggle worksheet events, screen updating and calculation mode off before and back on after (with error handling), and if that's still not enough I'd figure out a way to work with an in-memory array instead of accessing a worksheet in a loop. Result should be pretty much instant.

Answer (score 4):

Taking your code and running [Rubberduck's *Smart Indenter*](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) turns it into this:

```
Sub bootstrap()

    Dim i, j, k, l, m, n As Integer
    l = 9
    For l = 9 To 508

        For j = 5 To 4040
            Randomize
            k = Int((4040 - 5 + 1) * Rnd + 5)

            Cells(j, l + 1).Value = Cells(k, 9).Value
        Next
        Columns(l + 2).Insert
    Next

End Sub
```

That's already more readable, but there are a number of issues:

- Avoid single-letter identifiers (**especially** `l`). Use meaningful names that you can read out loud without sounding like you're speaking Klingon.
- Avoid declaring multiple variables in a single instruction - in this case only `n` has a type, everything else is an implicit `Variant`. At least they're declared, so, kudos for that! Declare an explicit type for all variables.
- Declaring variables closer to their usage makes **unused variables** much easier to spot. Noticed `n` isn't used anywhere? Remove it.
- Procedure names should be `PascalCase`, so, `Bootstrap` would be a better name. Module members are also `Public` by default, and access modifiers should usually be explicit, so `Public Sub Foo()` is better than just `Sub Foo()`.
- There's no need to `Randomize` at every single iteration of `j`. Call it once at the beginning of the procedure and be done with it.
- You need 500 iterations for `l` - that would be much clearer if the loop read `For l = 1 To 500`. Write code that says what it does, and does what it says. Don't make the reader/maintainer need to do mental math to figure out whether the loop is correct or possibly off-by-one; the code's cognitive load is enough already.
- Assuming you change the loop as above, avoid magic numbers. The `8` in the `l + 8` offset should be declared as a local constant with a meaningful name.
- Same for the `j` loop. `For j = 1 To 4036` makes the number of iterations plain & clear.
- You're implicitly working off the `ActiveSheet`, which is implicitly in the `ActiveWorkbook`. If the worksheet exists at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook` (the book with the code), then you should be using the global-scope worksheet `CodeName` that VBA is creating for you for free, instead of dereferencing it through `Excel.[_Global]` (a hidden module) at every single iteration. For example `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` in an empty, default workbook, can be referred to as `Sheet1.Range("A1")` without needing to declare anything.
- Reading, and especially *writing*, to a worksheet in a loop, is quite possibly the single slowest thing you can do in Excel VBA.
- Worksheet writes trigger `Worksheet.Change` events, recalculations (or at least checks for need-to-recalc), and repaints. You can turn off all those by toggling `Application.EnableEvents`, `Application.Calculation` and `Application.ScreenUpdating`, respectively. Toggle them off at the start, and back on before exiting. Note that a run-time error inside the loop is also an exit point, so you need to handle errors if you want to be 100% sure that your code will be toggling everything back on before it exits.

If that's still too slow, read your source range into a 2D variant array (perhaps start with the resizing / column-inserting, *then* read the range into an array), do the writes in the array, and after the loop is done just dump the array onto the worksheet - making all these worksheet writes a single pretty-much-instantaneous operation.

---

> **Disclaimer**: I own Rubberduck's website, and manage this open-source VBIDE add-in project.

Comment: (+1) Not only is there not a need to use `Randomize` in every pass through the loop, it is probably positively harmful for statistical validity. See this answer for a nice way to visualize the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41104557/4996248

Comment: Great post.  I would, however, place recommend using an array at the top of the list and not as a last resort.

Comment: @ThomasInzina I did consider, but didn't want to dive into the implications of the range being resized (/columns added) during the iteration - much refactoring would be needed to maintain the same result while working with an array, ..but you're right, it would totally be the preferred way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is actually all the screen updating stuff that was taking time. It now runs in less than 30 sec. Concerning all your other remarks, I'm well aware the code is bad, but I am not a programmer, I just need it to run, be it in less than 1 sec or 2mn.

Comment: @ThéophileDespres FWIW "I'm not a programmer" is even more of a reason to make sure your code is easy to read and maintain!

Answer (score 1):

I detect that your code set only `n` as an integer, and other variables are set as **variant**. Variant uses a lot of memory resources. I also added a `ScreenUpdating` function to reduce memory consumption.

```
Sub bootstrap()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

l = 9
For l = 9 To 508

    For j = 5 To 4040
         Randomize
         k = Int((4040 - 5 + 1) * Rnd + 5)

        Cells(j, l + 1).Value = Cells(k, 9).Value
    Next
Columns(l + 2).Insert
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if using an array to populate your values (store array in memory) and read it will be faster than reading Worsheet.cells every time.

Comment: it absolutely will. Also the implicit `Variant` thing has more to do with implicit type conversions and variant overhead than memory consumption, which has little impact on performance. None of this answer isn't already covered in mine.

Comment: So it is not possible to dim more than 1 variable at a time ? I mean dim i, j as integer is not the same as dim i as integer, j as integer ?

Comment: @ThéophileDespres no, in VBA it's not. In VB.NET it is, but not in VBA. In VBA every variable needs an explicit type, otherwise it's an implicit `Variant`.

Answer (score 1):

I find your rationale for doing this in VBA to be unconvincing ("R functions don't allow to extract every resampled series, so I had to do it with Excel and rnd"). Even if some specific bootstrap function that you are using doesn't have this functionality, it is very straightforward to do this sort of thing in R.

Given a sample vector `x`, the base R function call `sample(x,replace = TRUE)` *is* a bootstrap resample. If you want to generate 500 bootstrap samples, use `replicate`:

```
m <- replicate(500, sample(x, replace = TRUE))
```

will create a 500-column matrix of bootstrap samples. Since R is optimized for this sort of thing and generates the samples by using compiled functions written in C, this runs very quickly, even when `x` has thousands of elements:

```
> x <- rnorm(4036)
> microbenchmark(replicate(500,sample(x,replace = TRUE)))
Unit: milliseconds
                                      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 replicate(500, sample(x, replace = TRUE)) 37.01776 38.09518 51.78771 41.88934 47.22004 103.0439   100
```

It thus takes less than a 10th of a second to generate such a 4036 x 500 matrix of samples (your results might of course differ, but even with a slower machine it should be less than a second).

There is of course nothing wrong with doing this sort of thing in VBA, but if you do so then it should be for a good reason (e.g. you are already using Excel in your project) rather than because you are under the mistaken belief that this is some gap in the functionality of R which only VBA can fill.

Comment: Well the rationale is that I didn't know the functions you're talking about ! But I'll try to use them ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to say that hasn't already been said.  I simple refactored the OP's code to use an array. Using `Range.Value` to read and write the values took **4.27 seconds** to execute. `Range.Value2` executed in **3.72 seconds**.

[MSDN- Range.Value2 Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-value2-property-excel): Remarks

The only difference between this property and the Value property is that the Value2 property doesn't use the Currency and Date data types. You can return values formatted with these data types as floating-point numbers by using the Double data type.

### Test

```
Sub CalculateRunTime_Seconds()
'PURPOSE: Determine how many seconds it took for code to completely run
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

'Remember time when macro starts
  StartTime = Timer

'*****************************
bootstrap2
'*****************************

'Determine how many seconds code took to run
  SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

'Notify user in seconds
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

### Refactored Code using an array

```
Sub bootstrap2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Const RowCount As Long = 4036
    Const ColumnCount As Long = 501

    Dim results As Variant
    Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, x As Integer

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        results = .Range("I5").Resize(RowCount, ColumnCount).Value2
        Randomize
        For x = 2 To UBound(results, 2)
            For j = 1 To UBound(results, 1)
                Randomize
                k = Int(RowCount * Rnd + 1)
                results(j, x) = results(k, 1)
            Next
        Next
        .Range("I5").Resize(RowCount, ColumnCount).Value2 = results
    End With

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```